# Insert rows into existing table that span a range specified in 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a table that shows the promotions on a group ID and weekly basis. I have a table that shows per group ID what promotion there was and how many weeks it lasted, including start date and end date.

I want to insert week nummer in this table so that if a promotion lasted 2 weeks I would see the group ID in two seperate rows with the two week numbers in a column next to it and a duplicate of all the other information.

I have tried to work with the model function, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it to my data.

My current table looks like:

```
GROUP_ID   PROMOTION_DESCRIPTION            START_DATE  END_DATE   WEEKS  START_YEARWEEK   END_YEARWEEK   MEDIA_SUPPORT
40284      Gehwol / Wartner 2e halve prijs  27-06-17    01-07-17   1      201726           201726         Radio
40315      Voordeelzakken En Dozen          26-06-17    09-07-17   2      201726           201727         Online Campagne
```

And I want it to look like:

```
GROUP_ID   WEEK     PROMOTION_DESCRIPTION              MEDIA_SUPPORT
40284      201706   Gehwol / Wartner 2e halve prijs    Radio
40315      201726   Voordeelzakken En Dozen            Online Campagne
40315      201727   Voordeelzakken En Dozen            Online Campagne
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by generating a calendar and joining that to the promotion data.

The below example creates a `calendar` subfactor that includes one record for each week (including week 53) for years 2017, 2018, 2019, then joins any `promotion` record whose `start_yearweek` and `end_yearweek` intersect with that calendar week.

```
WITH CALENDAR AS (
    SELECT (100 * YEAR_OFFSET) + WEEK_OFFSET AS CALENDAR_WEEK
    FROM (
        SELECT LEVEL AS WEEK_OFFSET
        FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 53)
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT 2016 + LEVEL AS YEAR_OFFSET
                         FROM DUAL
                         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3))
SELECT GROUP_ID,
    CALENDAR_WEEK,
    PROMOTION_DESCRIPTION,
    MEDIA_SUPPORT
FROM CALENDAR
         INNER JOIN PROMOTION
ON CALENDAR_WEEK
    BETWEEN START_YEARWEEK AND END_YEAR_WEEK;
```

Result:

```
  GROUP_ID   CALENDAR_WEEK PROMOTION_DESCRIPTION             MEDIA_SUPPORT
     40284          201726 Gehwol / Wartner 2e halve prijs   Radio
     40315          201726 Voordeelzakken En Dozen           Online Campagne
     40315          201727 Voordeelzakken En Dozen           Online Campagne


3 rows selected.
```

EDIT: To generate an ISO-Week calendar, one can use the 'IW' format mask in `TO_DATE`.

This example calendar generates ISO weeks from 2014 through 2022:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR((DATE '2014-01-01' + LEVEL),'YYYYIW'))
    AS ISO_CALENDAR_WEEK FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY (DATE '2014-01-01' + LEVEL) < DATE '2023-01-01';
```

In the promotion example, this could be used as:

```
WITH CALENDAR AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR((DATE '2014-01-01' + LEVEL),'YYYYIW'))
        AS ISO_CALENDAR_WEEK FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY (DATE '2014-01-01' + LEVEL) < DATE '2023-01-01' )
SELECT GROUP_ID,
    ISO_CALENDAR_WEEK,
    PROMOTION_DESCRIPTION,
    MEDIA_SUPPORT
FROM CALENDAR
         INNER JOIN PROMOTION
ON ISO_CALENDAR_WEEK
    BETWEEN START_YEARWEEK AND END_YEAR_WEEK;
```

Result:

```
  GROUP_ID   ISO_CALENDAR_WEEK PROMOTION_DESCRIPTION             MEDIA_SUPPORT
     40315              201727 Voordeelzakken En Dozen           Online Campagne
     40284              201726 Gehwol / Wartner 2e halve prijs   Radio
     40315              201726 Voordeelzakken En Dozen           Online Campagne


3 rows selected.
```

Comment: Hey Alexgibbs, this is a great answer and works like a charm! Only I am working with ISO weeks, so they only go to week 52 for 2016-2018, but has 53 weeks in 2015. If I have to combine that data, how would you recommend I do that? I could easily remove the extra weeks in the years with 52 weeks, but is there any way to automate that when creating calendar? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @J4YJ4Y.  Sure thing the calendar can be nuanced as needed.  I'll update with an ISO example.

Comment: Ok @J4YJ4Y an example with ISO weeks has been added

Answer (score 0):

This recursive query can do it:

```
with c(rn, group_id, week, weeks, promotion_description, media_support) as (
  select 1, group_id, start_yearweek, weeks, promotion_description, media_support from t 
  union all
  select rn + 1, group_id, week + 1, weeks, promotion_description, media_support 
    from c where rn < weeks)
select group_id, week, weeks, promotion_description, media_support from c
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=90fa9576ac21da12af0537cf865355a1)</sup>**

Comment: Hey Ponder, thank you for the quick reply! While this would work for 2 week promotions, what would it do if I had a 33 week lasting promotion?

Comment: No, recursive query works for any number of weeks, it will produce 33 rows for that entry. Here is [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cf599ab91bbfb0eed7e7a579671c344b) where I added row with 33 weeks. The problem is only when year changes, we have to assign last week (as I understood), which requires some date transformations. In my demo you can see an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a combination `connect by level` style below to produce more rows depending on your data and to restrict them to a certain amount by controlling with `distinct` keyword.

```
with t( group_id, promotion_description, start_yearweek, end_yearweek, media_support ) as
(
 select 40284, 'Gehwol / Wartner 2e halve prijs', 201726, 201726, 'Radio' from dual union all
 select 40315, 'Voordeelzakken En Dozen', 201726, 201727, 'Online Campagne' from dual 
), t1 as
(
  select group_id,  
         sum(end_yearweek - start_yearweek + 1 ) as weeks
    from t
   group by group_id    
  )
  select distinct t1.group_id, start_yearweek + level - 1 as week,
         promotion_description, media_support 
   from t1
   join t on t1.group_id = t.group_id   
 connect by level <= weeks
  order by group_id, week;

 GROUP_ID   WEEK    PROMOTION_DESCRIPTION            MEDIA_SUPPORT
 --------   ------  -------------------------------  ---------------
 40284      201726  Gehwol / Wartner 2e halve prijs  Radio
 40315      201726  Voordeelzakken En Dozen          Online Campagne
 40315      201727  Voordeelzakken En Dozen          Online Campagne
```

*P.S. There's no need to hold a `weeks` column which might be calculated through the query.*

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/HBD80517)</kbd>

Comment: Hey Barbaros, thanks for this excellent answer! It seems to work, until I have a promotion that lasts 4 weeks and starts in week 52 of the year. Then suddenly instead of 4 rows I have 52 rows.. Is there some way to correct for that? Like work with date?

Comment: @J4YJ4Y you're welcome. The number of produced rows depend on the difference between `start_yearweek` and `end_yearweek` for each `group_id`. This can be observed as we add more sample select statements to the query which creates table `t`.